# Highcharts - Pie and showInLegend

Tags: highcharts

How can you hide only one serie by pie chart in chart legend? I have tried it with showInLegend Attributte in Serie but it doesnt work.

```
[{ y: 0, name: 'Serie A', color: '#D93600', showInLegend: true}, { y: 0, name: 'Serie B', color: '#F8ADA7', showInLegend: false}]
```

Comment: showInLegend can be set only for serie, not particular point.

Comment: Please rephrase your question as I am not getting what are you trying to say. If possible provide some reference examples ot explain your problem

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to hide elements in legend for a pie chart. Did you solve it?